# Displaying PDF files without toolbars using Acrobat Reader ActiveX in LabVIEW

Tags: pdf, activex, acrobat, labview

How do I show PDF files full view wiwthout toolbars in Labview with activeX? I currently have it setup, and it seems that with 1 Page PDF files, it works perfectly, but with 2 page PDF files it shows with all of the toolbars.[image: Adobe Reader in Labview]

Comment: "I currently have it setup ... " Do you have some code. In your graphic setShowToolbar should be set to false.

Answer (score 0):

In general something like this should work also for a file with more pages:

```
oPDF = ObjCreate("AcroPDF.PDF.1")
oPdf.LoadFile("d:\test2.pdf")
oPDF.SetShowToolbar(false)
```

From the command line you can use:

```
AcroRd32.exe /a "toolbar=0=OpenActions" "D:\Test2.pdf"
```

Comment: I am trying to load this through an activex control in the main vi

Comment: That is in the first part of the answer "oPDF.SetShowToolbar(false)". That is working for me via activex in a GUI independet from PDF pages.Does other command like: "oPDF.SetZoom(120)" work in your app?

Comment: I notice that the LabVIEW code first calls 'setShowToolbar' then specifies the filename. In your answer the order is different.

Comment: Yes you should change that. Also the values for show NOT (hide): are "false" or "0" (zero), for show: true or 1. In your graphic you have set "on", that may lead to problems.